# Two men and a bird go on a journey

Tags: riddle

> Two men and a bird
>
> Forgetting a third
>
> A calm sea they found
>
> And marked up the ground
>
> And now far away
>
> The memories stay

What journey was this?

Hint:

> This actually happened.

Further hint:

> But only once.

Comment: Sounds like something with pirates to me...

Comment: It does sound like it involves pirates, but it doesn't. Every line is relevant here.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Answer:**

> Apollo 11 Moon Landing

**Explanation:**

Two men and a bird

> Neil Armstrong and Edwin "Buzz" Aldrin rode in the lander, which was named "Eagle"

Forgetting a third

> Michael Collins stayed behind in the command module

A calm sea they found

> They landed at an area named "Sea of Tranquility"

And marked up the ground

> "One small step for man... "

And now far away

> The moon is far away

The memories stay

> Parts of expedition, including the base of the Eagle and the US flag remained behind at the landing site.

Source:

> [Wikipedia: Apollo 11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apollo_11)

Comment: This is correct! Well done!

Comment: You're welcome! I had a fun time making it.

Answer (score 5):

The answer is

> the Lewis and Clark expedition.

Two men and a bird

> The two men were Lewis and Clark, and they were accompanied by Sacagawea, which translates to "bird woman."

Forgetting a third

> Not sure what this means.

A calm sea they found

> The Pacific Ocean, pacific meaning "calm" or "peaceful."

And marked up the ground

> They created maps along their journey.

And now far away

> It happened a while ago.

The memories stay

> But is still remembered and taught in American history.

Comment: Very thoughtful, but this wasn't what I was thinking about and you didn't handle the third person. This third person was a specific person that was explicitly and intentionally left behind.

Comment: Wow, when I looked up Sacagawea and saw it meant bird woman, I was sure that this would be the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

> Are you talking about **Cordobas family / Mr Alvarenga**

-

> THE two fishermen had been lost at sea for around four months when the younger one, Ezequiel Cordoba, 22, finally gave up.

-

> source [Link](http://www.express.co.uk/comment/expresscomment/627336/Castaway-cannibal-Ezequiel-Cordoba-Salvador-Alvarenga)

Comment: No, but a good guess. Where's the bird? Nobody died on the journey that I'm thinking of.